# Read one line from file/pipe and reuse it in a while loop

Tags: perl, while-loop, seek

I have a file handle to read data from a file or from a pipe. Firstly, I read one line from the file handle. Then, I need to execute a `while` loop, taking into account the previously-read line. I think the [`seek` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/seek.html) is problematic with pipes.

So my pseudocode is

```
local $line = <INPUT>;
seek(INPUT, -length($line), 1);
# if block
while (<INPUT>) {

}
```

Perhaps, there is a solution like this one?

```
while ($line, <INPUT>) {

}
```

Comment: It's called a "file handle", not a "filehandler". It holds onto a file resources; it doesn't take care of a file resource.

Comment: A lot depends on why you want to do this. The easiest way is just to write a `while` read loop and save the line the first time it is executed. There's probably no need to read the first line and then also feed it into the read loop

Comment: I needed to read the first line to determine the type of output and then I need to process the output accordingly since the first line. In fact, I have two possible output types and so I have two different while loops to apply. But I need to process also the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remember the first line in a variable. Read the next line from the filehandle at the end of the loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $FH, '-|', 'echo 3 ; seq 1 10' or die $!;
if (defined( my $first = <$FH> )) {
    my $line = $first;
    while () {
        chomp $line;
        print "$line:$first";
        last if eof $FH;

        $line = <$FH>;
    }
}
```

Comment: so simple that I didn't realize ... :-D

Answer (score 3):

Looking backward:

```
my $prev;
while (defined( my $line = <> )) {
   ... Use $prev and $line. $prev might not be defined. ...

   $prev = $line;
}
```

Looking forward:

```
my $line = <>;
while (defined($line)) {
   my $next = <>;
   ... Use $line and $next. $next might not be defined. ...

   $line = $next;
}
```

In pairs:

```
if (defined( my $line1 = <> )) {
   while (defined( my $line2 = <> )) {
      ... Use $line1 and $line2. Both will be defined. ...

      $line1 = $line2;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on why you want to do this. The easiest way is just to write a while read loop and save the line the first time it is executed. There's probably no need to read the first line and then also feed it into the read loop

Something like this perhaps

```
my $first_line;

while ( <> ) {

    $first_line //= $_;

    # Process $_
}
```